# Detectron2 deployment using TorchScript and Visual Studio 2019 in C++

Tags: c++, deployment, visual-studio-2019, detectron

[image: Command used to export the model]

I have with me the exported file which is a TS file.
[image: Exported model file]

I cannot understand what does the next command after exporting the model does.
./build/torchscript_mask_rcnn output/model.ts input.jpg scripting.

I have followed this example for doing this:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/tree/main/tools/deploy

[image: torchscript_mask_rcnn]

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/tree/main/tools/deploy)!
The second point states that it contains A C++ example that runs inference with Mask R-CNN model in TorchScript format.
For further issues and explanations visit this:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/2582#issuecomment-814551732